# speech api for android

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I am working in speech recognition in android. I want to use java speech api . Can i use that for android or there is a better api for android ?????
 note: I want to match two audio file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo speech recognition the RECOGNIZE_SPEECH Intent is probably the easiest way. [Check the introduction to Speech Input](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html) for more details.